# Gold Movies script, gold.php error

Tags: php

I'm using the Gold Movies script and if I try for add a movie I see this empty page:

```
http://yourdomain.com/gold-app/gold-includes/GOLD.php
```

In the begin of the Gold.php file there is this:

```
<?
// --- GOLD MEDIA --- //
error_reporting(0);
session_start();

define('GOLD_BASE', dirname(empty($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) ? __FILE__ : $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/');
$document = '' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . dirname('../../', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

require_once('../../gold-config.php');
require_once('TMDb.php');
```

If I add the tags `<?php  ?>` not change nothing.
Suggestions?